# Why can't I navigate into my Documents directory?

Tags: bash, directory, directory-structure

I'm in bash and running F17 as su. My `pwd` is

```
/home/user
```

and when I `ls` I see

```
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
```

However, I'm unable to `cd` into any of these. My error is

```
bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory
```

How come?

Comment: What error message appears when you try to `cd` into them?

Comment: bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory

Comment: Wild guess: perhaps you are already in your Desktop directory? `cd` will not produce any output if successful

Comment: @Islay: What does `ls -l` say? Guess: Desktop is a stale link...

Comment: @Gowtham When I 'ls -l' I get the following output: drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 4096 August 15 08:16 Desktop

Comment: can you `cd /home/user/Desktop`

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l $HOME`.

Comment: @jmathew I can't; I get the same error

Comment: @bahamat My output is: '-rw-------. 1 root root 1177 Aug 15 04:06 anaconda-ks.cfg'

Comment: You said when you `ls` you see `Desktop ...`. Can you do that again, but also run `pwd` before and after and show the output?

Comment: If you run `LC_ALL=C ls -FQ` in your home directory, what do you see? (At least the entry that contains `Desktop`.)

Comment: @bahamat `pwd; ls; pwd;` prints `/home/user` `Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Video` `/home/user`.

Comment: @Gilles `LC_ALL=C ls -FQ` prints the `user` directory, except not in blue.

Comment: @Gilles ah, I see `.pulse-cookie .gstreamer-0.10 .ICEauthority .gimp-2.8 .imsettings.log .gitconfig` and various others including `.bashrc .gconf .dbus`. What does the '.' signify?

Comment: @Islay You clearly didn't pass `-FQ` to `ls`, and passed `-a` instead. Please copy-paste the command I gave you (except for changing the user name), I'm trying to see if there's an invisible character in the directory name and nothing you've posted so far tells us whether that's the case.

Comment: @Gilles woops, here's the actual output: `"Desktop"/    "Downloads"/  "Pictures"/  "Public"/     "Videos"/
"Documents"/  "Music"/     "Practice"/  "Templates"/`

Comment: @Islay Ok, so the directory is really called `Desktop`, it's not that. And it is a directory and not a symbolic link.

Comment: Please execute the following commands in order and also copy the output verbatim (including the command line!) into your question: `pwd`, `whoami`, `ls -l`, `cd Desktop`. The important part is the verbatim thing, just copy *everything*.

Comment: What is output of "ls -ld Desktop" (note -d here)? OTOH, are you sure this is "Desktop" but not e.g. "Desktop " (with extra space)?

Comment: You need to do a : `ls -ald .    */`  (note that "." and "*/" are separated by space). And see if it's not a user issue (ex: if they all belong to root root, and are only readable / executable by root, then you'll see those problems). It's possible you have righs in "." to see the files, and no read/execute permission on the subfolders preventing the cd

Comment: in addition to running "whoami" please run "id" id gives far more useful info than whoami for these sorts of problems.
I'd also run "ls -ln" the permissions really operate on the numeric values not the symbolic names of users and groups.
In fact, please run this - it will also let us see the SElinux file contexts if any - id will show your user context, if any:
 pwd; ls -lZ . : ls -lZn .; ls -lZ ; ls -lZn; id

Comment: Did you ever assign an alias to `cd`?

Answer (score 2):

It is almost always the case that "when root cannot do something root should be able to do, the problem is selinux".

As it's been months, the situation has probably been remedied, but if someone else has a similar problem and see this post, I recommend running "setenforce 0" which will put selinux in "permissive" mode until the next reboot (or until "setenforce 1" is run).  See if that fixes it such that you can cd into Desktop.

If that fixes it, then you will need to either restore the selinux context for /home/user, or change the selinux policy for files under /home.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `~/.bashrc` file and see if you have an alias defined for `cd`.
Does this happen as any other user or just yours?  Is it only the Desktop directory or all directories in your home folder?

Comment: It's all sub directories of my user directory: /home/user